# C : what does "?" mean?

Tags: linux, c

```
1:snprintf(       buf, sizeof(buf),
2:                "%s exe=%s hostname=%s addr=%s terminal=%s res=%s",
3:                message, exename,
4:                hostname ? hostname : "?",
5:                addrbuf,
6:                tty ? tty : "?",
7:                success
                );
```

In the above code in line number 6, what does "?" represents (not the ternary operator)

What does `tty : tty : "?"` mean?

Comment: `"?"` is the string literal consisting of the character `?` here. What are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: [?: operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 5):

In line 6,

```
tty ? tty : "?"
```

the first ? is the ternary operator. The second one, in quotes, is a question mark character in a character string of length 1 (one character plus a null terminator).

So that line says that if tty is not null, use tty, otherwise use the string "?".

Answer (score 0):

If `tty` is `NULL`, `snprintf()` will *output* the string `"?"` (one character) instead of causing UB if you just stick with `tty`.

```
char *tty = NULL;
printf("%s", tty); // UB
printf("%s", "?"); // print a 1-character string
printf("%s", tty?tty:"?"); // print tty's value or ?
```